# Method returns blank even though it isn't blank inside method

Tags: python

I have written a small scrip (this is partial), the full code should search a bunch of .c files and check if the parameters within it are being used or not. This particular code is responsible for grabbing the parameter from a row, so it can be used to search the .c files for identical parameter names and it's values.

The issue is that the first instant of print (inside `takeTheParam` method) shows the correct parameter in command prompt, while the second print instant (after the call to the `takeTheParam` method) shows a blank in command prompt.

```
import os

theParam = ""

def takeTheParam(row, theParam):
    for item in row.split():
        if "_" in item:
            theParam = item
            print theParam
            return theParam


for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/pathtoworkdir'):
    for cFile in files:
        if cFile.endswith('.c'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, cFile), 'r') as this:
                for row in this:
                    if '=' in row:
                        takeTheParam(row, theParam)
                        print theParam
                        while theParam not in usedParameters:  # Has the param already been checked?
                            value(row, savedValue, statements, cur)
                            searchAndValueExtract(theParam, parameterCounter, compareValue)
                            while isEqual(savedValue, compareValue, equalValueCounter):
                                searchAndValueExtract(theParam, parameterCounter, compareValue)
                            else:
                                # If IsEqual returns false, that means a param has different values 
                                # and it's therefore being used
                                usedParameters.append(theParam)
                                pass
```

I have't got enough experience in python to figure out why this happens, but I suspect that when `theParam` is used outside of the method it's value it retrieved from it's definition on the beginning  of the code (`theParam = ""`) and I have no idea why, if this is the case.

Comment: The similar name of the variable and the one used in the function declaration is fooling you. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/2564301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
 takeTheParam(row, theParam)
```

to

```
theParam = takeTheParam(row, theParam)
```

The returned variable is never assigned to `theParam` in your case, so it would stay `""` forever. Now it isn't anymore.

Comment: It's working for `takeTheParam` but what should I do if one of my methods return two values?

Comment: then you would do `param1, param2 = func_that_returns_two_variables()`. And return within that function with `return param1, param2`